# Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon throws COMException

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms-interop, system.drawing.imaging

I use `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` method to convert `Icon` to `BitmapSource`:

```
private static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource loadWpfImageSource(Icon icon, Size size)
    {
        if (icon != null)
        {
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

At one of my client's computer `Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` throws the next `COMException`:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007057A): Wrong pointer descriptor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007057A)
at System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap..ctor(IntPtr hicon, Int32Rect sourceRect, BitmapSizeOptions sizeOptions)
at System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(IntPtr icon, Int32Rect sourceRect, BitmapSizeOptions sizeOptions)
```

Any ideas why could this happen? (And how to fix it)

Comment: The error message is wrong.  This is a low-level Windows error, error code 1402, ERROR_INVALID_CURSOR_HANDLE, "Invalid cursor handle".  Icons and cursors are almost indistinguishable.  A simple explanation is that the icon is corrupted or invalid, that can happen of course.

Comment: @Hans Passant: if an icon is corrupted, does it mean that if I convert  `Icon` through the way that uses `MemoryStream`, the `Icon` will fail to convert anyway?